# Can motherboard USB 2.0 port be used to move files between two USB 3.0 devices connected to 3.0 hub?

Tags: usb, motherboard, external-hard-drive, power, file-transfer

If I purchase a powered USB 3.0 hub (ie: http://a.co/dAHmCOv) and connected it to my PC (which currently only has a USB 2.0 capable motherboard/ports) will I be able to drag and drop files between two USB 3.0 devices connected to the hub...at 3.0 speeds? Since the data is going from one USB 3.0 device to another, through a 3.0 hub?

Comment: That would be an interesting feature to add to future USB but the data goes from the hub to the host and back at 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will I be able to drag and drop files between two USB 3.0 devices connected to the hub...at 3.0 speeds?

No, the data isn't going directly from one to another. And any USB3.0 device connected to an USB2.0 port, including hubs, will automatically fallback to the 2.0 specifications.